# Analyzing Logical Forms involving quantifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I have been solving the following problem from `How to Prove` book:

> Analyze the logical forms of the following statement:
>
> Everyone likes
>   Mary, except Mary herself.

Now, the above sentence conveys the following meaning (to me): Everyone likes Mary but she doesn't like herself.

And I have translated it into the following logical forms:

```
L(x,y) = x likes y
∀x L(x,m) ∧ ¬L(m,m)  (m refers to Mary)
```

But the answer is something like this:

```
∀x(¬(x = m) → L(x, m)), where L(x, y) stands for “x likes y,” and
m stands for Mary.
```

How does implication come here ? What is the thought process involved
here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\forall x, x\ne m\Rightarrow L(x,m)$.

The only person who doesn't like Mary is Mary herself.  So if someone doesn't like Mary, that someone must be Mary.  Or the contrapositive; if someone isn't Mary, that someone likes Mary.

In your formulation, you have Mary liking Mary ($\forall x L(x,m)$) and Mary not liking Mary ($\neg L(m,m)$).  These two conjuncted form a contradiction.